# Insert a loading message into DataGrid

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I'd like to show a loading message (Loading...) that shows while the datagrid is being populated.

It would show when the search button is clicked and disappear when the grid results have populated.

I've seen a few possible options including [dojox.widget.Standby](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/widget/Standby) however, it looks like there is something that is already embedded in the [dojox.grid.DataGrid](http://higginsforpresident.net/api/dojox/grid/_Grid.html#loadingMessage)

I can't find any documentation on how to access it or show it in my app. Anybody had any luck inserting a loading message in their app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method I've found to do this is by using:

```
grid.hideMessage("Loading...");
```

and

```
grid.showMessage("Loading...");
```

It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it does the trick and is only 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to pass it into the constructor as an option:

```
var grid = new DataGrid({
loadingMessage: "Loading...",
/* all your stuff */
});
```

You will probably get better answers faster relating to Dojo over on http://stackoverflow.com .

Comment: thanks. I tried it over there. I did find a span tag that accesses the loading message within dojox.grid.DataGrid but can't figure out how to use it properly